# Objective-c [For loop] load HTML in UIWebview and retrieve data from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, objective-c, json, uiwebview

I'm making an app in Objective-c for IOS and I need to be able to loop through a bunch of web pages and, using an embedded javascript function return some JSON values.

I use the pages elsewhere in the app and the javascript works as required. At this point I do store the JSON response but as user might not view every page the app wont necessarily have all the JSON values to check.

The section of code below is what I'm using to loop through all the pages, load in the HTML string and run the javascript function. The problem is that the values always come back empty.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"finished loading");
    NSString *jsonValues = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getFields()"];
}

for (int i = 1; i <= shifts; i++)
    {
        ontracMultipleWevViewController *RT9909 = [viewControllerDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shift %d RT9909", i]];
        if (RT9909 && [RT9909.viewControllers count] > 0) {
            for (ontracRTViewController *r9909 in RT9909.viewControllers) {

                 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
                 [webView setDelegate: self];
                 [webView loadHTMLString:r9909.htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:r9909.urlToLoad]];
                [self webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
                [self.view addSubview:webView];

                if([self webViewDidFinishLoad:webView]){
                    r9909.jsonValues = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getFields()"];

                   if(r9909.jsonValues != nil && ![r9909.jsonValues isEqualToString:@""] && rt9909ShiftCount == 0){

                   ........rest of code
```

NOTE: I get no error or NSLogs to suggest any problems

Comment: You are calling your self `webViewDidFinishLoad:`? Shouldn't it the delegate that calls it when the webView has done loading?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your reply, I forgot to add that method actually.

Comment: @Larme Also forgot all about the delegate, going to look into that now. Thanks

Comment: @Larme I've updated my question with the code to include the delegate (also added UIWebviewDelegate to the .h file). Still having the same issue though

Comment: You don't understand the delegate pattern, and that this call should be asynchronous. Don't call yourself `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. My guess, is that you didn't passed the `if([self webViewDidFinishLoad:webView])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to segregate the

```
if([self webViewDidFinishLoad:webView]){
    r9909.jsonValues = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getFields()"];
```

block out of the `for-loop` & add `tags` to your webviews.

Implement the

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

optional delegate function of `UIWebView` & put in your

```
if(...) {
      r9909.jsonValues = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getFields()"];
 }
```

logic here.
 The `if check` would now be based on the `webview.tag` that you will assign will creating the webviews inside the `for loop`.

Comment: Make sure you tab code blocks 4 spaces over instead of using ```, edited the format for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @yStack I'm not sure I can go without the `for-loop` as I need to iterate through `x` number of shifts

Comment: @jampez77 The `for-loop` continues to exist, just that you (programmatically) don't invoke the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` function. When the webview, actually finishes loading its content, OS will invoke `webViewDidFinishLoad:` & you continue performing your operations from there on.

Comment: @yStack Ah ok, i'm with you now. The issue is that `webViewDidFinishLoad` is not called by OS.